# Android - How to decode this Html to Json or String?

Tags: android, json

I get content from link API:
http://lichngaytot.com/TongHopAjax/Ngam?categoryId=284&pageIndex=1

But server return data with format as follows:

```
"\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-smartphone-chuan-ngu-hanh-sanh-dieu-ma-van-hop-phong-thuy-284-183919.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Chọn smartphone chuẩn ngũ hành, sành điệu mà vẫn hợp phong thủy\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/24/Chon-smartphone-chuan-ngu-hanh,-sanh-dieu-ma-van-hop-phong-thuy.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-smartphone-chuan-ngu-hanh-sanh-dieu-ma-van-hop-phong-thuy-284-183919.html\u0027\u003eChọn smartphone chuẩn ngũ hành, sành điệu mà vẫn hợp phong thủy\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e (Lichngaytot.com) Nếu hiểu được bản chất của màu sắc ngũ hành mà mình thích thì bạn có thể dễ dàng biết cách điều chế phong thủy trở nên tốt đẹp hơn. Tự mình xem xét và chọn ra chiếc điện thoại di động phù hợp với mình nhất, nói qua thì có vẻ khó nhưng thực chất lại rất đơn giản.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/7-dieu-kieng-ki-trong-tiet-thanh-minh-284-183918.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u00277 điều kiêng kị trong tiết Thanh Minh\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/24/7-dieu-kieng-ki-trong-tiet-Thanh-Minh.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/7-dieu-kieng-ki-trong-tiet-thanh-minh-284-183918.html\u0027\u003e7 điều kiêng kị trong tiết Thanh Minh\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Tiết Thanh Minh là dịp lễ truyền thống của người Việt, gắn liền với tục tảo mộ nhớ đến tổ tiên. 7 điều kiêng kị trong tiết Thanh Minh sẽ giúp bạn không phạm lỗi trong những ngày này.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-mo-pham-bi-thach-doan-phap-284-183906.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u002710 thế mộ hung hiểm trong phong thủy âm trạch: Mộ phạm bi thạch đoạn pháp\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/23/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-Mo-pham-bi-thach-doan-phap.JPG\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-mo-pham-bi-thach-doan-phap-284-183906.html\u0027\u003e10 thế mộ hung hiểm trong phong thủy âm trạch: Mộ phạm bi thạch đoạn pháp\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Bi thạch đoạn pháp là thế mộ hung hiểm thứ hai trong phong thủy âm trạch. Nên đọc để tránh mang họa cho cả nhà.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-mo-pham-bon-than-doan-phap-284-183899.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u002710 thế mộ hung hiểm trong phong thủy âm trạch: Mộ phạm bổn thân đoạn pháp\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/23/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-Mo-pham-bon-than-doan-phap.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/10-the-mo-hung-hiem-trong-phong-thuy-am-trach-mo-pham-bon-than-doan-phap-284-183899.html\u0027\u003e10 thế mộ hung hiểm trong phong thủy âm trạch: Mộ phạm bổn thân đoạn pháp\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Phong thủy âm trạch có ảnh hưởng đặc biệt tới cuộc sống của con cháu trong nhà, nên nhìn vào mộ phần có thể luận đoán cát hung sau này. Mộ phần phạm bổn thân đoạn pháp là một trong 10 thế mộ hung hiểm.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/sap-xep-lai-goc-lam-viec-su-nghiep-thang-cap-bat-ngo-284-183893.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Sắp xếp lại góc làm việc, sự nghiệp thăng cấp bất ngờ\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/23/Sap-xep-lai-goc-lam-viec,-su-nghiep-thang-cap-bat-ngo.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/sap-xep-lai-goc-lam-viec-su-nghiep-thang-cap-bat-ngo-284-183893.html\u0027\u003eSắp xếp lại góc làm việc, sự nghiệp thăng cấp bất ngờ\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Di chuyển, sắp xếp đơn giản tại góc làm việc cũng đồng nghĩa với thay đổi nguồn năng lượng ở khu vực này. Thay đổi tích cực sẽ mang tới nhiều may mắn và ngược lại.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nhan-dien-phong-thuy-tot-bang-chinh-ban-than-minh-284-183885.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Nhận diện phong thủy tốt bằng chính bản thân mình\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/22/Nhan-dien-phong-thuy-tot-bang-chinh-ban-than-minh.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nhan-dien-phong-thuy-tot-bang-chinh-ban-than-minh-284-183885.html\u0027\u003eNhận diện phong thủy tốt bằng chính bản thân mình\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Phong chính là nguyên khí, Thủy chính là sự lưu thông của dòng khí. Nếu chỉ phán đoán phong thủy qua phương hướng hay cách bài trí mà không nói tới nhân tố con người thì đó chưa thực sự là phong thủy.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/dinh-nghia-phong-thuy-va-nhung-yeu-to-chi-phoi-phong-thuy-284-183871.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Định nghĩa về phong thủy và những yếu tố chi phối phong thủy\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/21/Dinh-nghia-ve-phong-thuy-va-nhung-yeu-to-chi-phoi-phong-thuy.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/dinh-nghia-phong-thuy-va-nhung-yeu-to-chi-phoi-phong-thuy-284-183871.html\u0027\u003eĐịnh nghĩa về phong thủy và những yếu tố chi phối phong thủy\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Mê tín là chỉ nhìn mọi việc khách quan mà không rõ nguyên căn, bản chất. Phong thủy không phải là mê tín, bản chất của phong thủy chính là sự kết hợp hài hòa giữa con người và thiên nhiên.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/kheo-dat-binh-uong-nuoc-tai-loc-gia-tang-khong-ngung-284-183862.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Khéo đặt bình uống nước, tài lộc gia tăng không ngừng\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/21/Kheo-dat-binh-uong-nuoc,-tai-loc-gia-tang-khong-ngung.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/kheo-dat-binh-uong-nuoc-tai-loc-gia-tang-khong-ngung-284-183862.html\u0027\u003eKhéo đặt bình uống nước, tài lộc gia tăng không ngừng\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Theo quan điểm phong thủy, bình uống nước thuộc tính Thủy, có liên quan đến tài lộc. Vị trí đặt bình uống nước đúng chuẩn góp phần thúc vượng tài vận cho gia đình.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-p2-284-183829.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u00278 cách hóa giải nhà khuyết góc theo quy tắc phong thủy (P2)\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/17/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-(P2).jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-p2-284-183829.html\u0027\u003e8 cách hóa giải nhà khuyết góc theo quy tắc phong thủy (P2)\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Người trong nhà liên tiếp bị bệnh hoặc công việc chưa thuận lợi, một số người đổ \"tại số\", nhưng thực chất, nguyên nhân nằm chính ở phong thủy ngôi nhà, hiện tượng khuyết góc gây ra những tai họa khó lường.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nghe-am-thanh-doan-cat-hung-phong-thuy-nha-o-284-183823.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Nghe âm thanh, đoán cát hung phong thủy nhà ở\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/16/Nghe-am-thanh,-doan-cat-hung-phong-thuy-nha-o.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nghe-am-thanh-doan-cat-hung-phong-thuy-nha-o-284-183823.html\u0027\u003eNghe âm thanh, đoán cát hung phong thủy nhà ở\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Làm thế nào để xác định phong thủy nhà ở của bạn là tốt hay xấu? Thử lắng nghe âm thanh phong thủy phát ra từ ngôi nhà xem sao nhé!\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/hieu-dung-cau-son-quan-nhan-dinh-thuy-quan-tai-keo-chon-phai-nha-phong-thuy-xau-284-183807.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Hiểu đúng câu \"Sơn quản nhân đinh, Thủy quản tài\" kẻo chọn phải nhà phong thủy xấu\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/15/Hieu-dung-cau-Son-quan-nhan-dinh,-Thuy-quan-tai-keo-chon-phai-nha-phong-thuy-xau.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/hieu-dung-cau-son-quan-nhan-dinh-thuy-quan-tai-keo-chon-phai-nha-phong-thuy-xau-284-183807.html\u0027\u003eHiểu đúng câu \"Sơn quản nhân đinh, Thủy quản tài\" kẻo chọn phải nhà phong thủy xấu\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Phong thủy có câu “Sơn quản nhân đinh, Thủy quản tài”, mua nhà mà chọn nơi có núi, có sông thì cực kì tốt. Nhưng khoan hãy vội, còn phải xem bạn hiểu đúng ý nghĩa của câu trên chưa đã nhé!\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-cay-phong-thuy-de-ban-tro-luc-nghe-nao-phat-nghe-do-284-183801.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Chọn cây phong thủy để bàn trợ lực nghề nào phát nghề đó\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/15/Chon-cay-phong-thuy-de-ban-tro-luc-nghe-nao-phat-nghe-do.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-cay-phong-thuy-de-ban-tro-luc-nghe-nao-phat-nghe-do-284-183801.html\u0027\u003eChọn cây phong thủy để bàn trợ lực nghề nào phát nghề đó\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Ngoài yếu tố con người, phong thủy văn phòng cũng tác động không nhỏ tới thành công trong công việc của mỗi người. Căn cứ vào mỗi ngành nghề khác nhau, bạn có thể lựa chọn cho mình loại cây phù hợp để thúc vượng sự nghiệp.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-p1-284-183800.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u00278 cách hóa giải nhà khuyết góc theo quy tắc phong thủy (P1)\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/15/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-(P1).jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/8-cach-hoa-giai-nha-khuyet-goc-theo-quy-tac-phong-thuy-p1-284-183800.html\u0027\u003e8 cách hóa giải nhà khuyết góc theo quy tắc phong thủy (P1)\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Quy tắc phong thủy nhà ở chuẩn nhất là âm dương hài hòa, thiên nhiên hợp nhất. Căn cứ vào nguyên lý thiên địa có thể suy luận dương trạch tốt nhất là hình vuông, như vậy mới có thể hấp thụ nguồn khí từ cả bốn phía cũng như là năng lương từ ngũ hành. Nhưng hầu hết những ngôi nhà hiện đại đều bị khuyết góc, gia chủ cần tìm phương pháp để hóa giải nếu không muốn gặp vận xui, gia đình lao đao.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/su-dung-kinh-sai-phong-thuy-gia-chu-hoang-mang-lo-lang-284-183791.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Sử dụng kính sai phong thủy, gia chủ hoang mang lo lắng\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/14/Su-dung-kinh-sai-phong-thuy,-gia-chu-hoang-mang-lo-lang.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/su-dung-kinh-sai-phong-thuy-gia-chu-hoang-mang-lo-lang-284-183791.html\u0027\u003eSử dụng kính sai phong thủy, gia chủ hoang mang lo lắng\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Sử dụng kính trong thiết kế, xây dựng văn phòng, nhà ở hiện nay là điều thường thấy. Nhưng nếu không tuân thủ nguyên lý phong thủy, những công trình sử dụng nhiều loại vật liệu này sẽ gây tác hại khó có thể lường hết được.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/yeu-to-phong-thuy-nao-khien-toi-lo-dang-trong-cong-viec-284-183738.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Tư vấn: Yếu tố phong thủy nào khiến tôi lơ đãng trong công việc?\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/10/Tu-van-Yeu-to-phong-thuy-nao-khien-toi-lo-dang-trong-cong-viec.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/yeu-to-phong-thuy-nao-khien-toi-lo-dang-trong-cong-viec-284-183738.html\u0027\u003eTư vấn: Yếu tố phong thủy nào khiến tôi lơ đãng trong công việc?\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Cùng Lichngaytot.com trả lời thắc mắc của chị Thu Thủy, Cầu Giấy, HN để hiểu rõ hơn về yếu tố phong thủy ảnh hưởng tới tinh thần làm việc.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/su-dung-tram-huong-cai-thien-phong-thuy-tang-tai-tien-loc-284-183732.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Sử dụng trầm hương cải thiện phong thủy, tăng tài tiến lộc\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/10/Su-dung-tram-huong-cai-thien-phong-thuy,-tang-tai-tien-loc.JPG\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/su-dung-tram-huong-cai-thien-phong-thuy-tang-tai-tien-loc-284-183732.html\u0027\u003eSử dụng trầm hương cải thiện phong thủy, tăng tài tiến lộc\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Trầm hương là hương liệu quý, ngoài dùng để cúng tế, lễ Phật thì còn có nhiều công dụng trong lĩnh vực phong thủy. Dưới đây là một số cách sử dụng trầm hương cải thiện phong thủy.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-p2-284-183727.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Phong thủy đồ lưu niệm: Rước may hay nhận xui? (P2)\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-Ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-(P2).jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-p2-284-183727.html\u0027\u003ePhong thủy đồ lưu niệm: Rước may hay nhận xui? (P2)\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Thường chúng ta chỉ coi những món đồ lưu niệm như là một vật kỷ niệm hoặc vật may mắn. Tuy nhiên, nếu không được sử dụng đúng cách thì chúng sẽ không còn là vật kỷ niệm đơn thuần, mà ngược lại, còn mang tới cho gia chủ những điều xui rủi.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/thay-doi-nho-trong-phong-thuy-nha-o-de-ca-nha-khoe-manh-284-183725.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Thay đổi nhỏ trong phong thủy nhà ở để cả nhà khỏe mạnh\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Thay-doi-nho-trong-phong-thuy-nha-o-de-ca-nha-khoe-manh.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/thay-doi-nho-trong-phong-thuy-nha-o-de-ca-nha-khoe-manh-284-183725.html\u0027\u003eThay đổi nhỏ trong phong thủy nhà ở để cả nhà khỏe mạnh\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Yếu tố phong thủy không chỉ ảnh hưởng tới tài lộc mà còn tác động khá lớn tới sức khỏe của mọi thành viên trong gia đình. Phong thủy tốt, sức khỏe dồi dào và ngược lại.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-p1-284-183723.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Phong thủy đồ lưu niệm: Rước may hay nhận xui? (P1)\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-Ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-(P1).jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-do-luu-niem-ruoc-may-hay-nhan-xui-p1-284-183723.html\u0027\u003ePhong thủy đồ lưu niệm: Rước may hay nhận xui? (P1)\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Những món đồ lưu niệm thường rất nhỏ xinh và khá nhiều khách du lịch có thói quen mua đồ lưu niệm về tặng người thân, bạn bè. Đây thường là những món đồ mang ý nghĩa may mắn, thế nhưng, nếu tùy ý sử dụng, chúng có thể phản tác dụng, mang lại những xui rủi không đáng có.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-phat-chau-hop-phong-thuy-de-tich-phuc-them-may-284-183721.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Chọn Phật châu hợp phong thủy để tích phúc, thêm may\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Chon-Phat-chau-hop-phong-thuy-de-tich-phuc,-them-may.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-phat-chau-hop-phong-thuy-de-tich-phuc-them-may-284-183721.html\u0027\u003eChọn Phật châu hợp phong thủy để tích phúc, thêm may\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Chọn Phật châu hợp ngũ hành không chỉ làm hưng vượng vận thế mà còn mang tới phúc khí, tự tích phúc cầu may cho bản thân. \u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-khai-van-tai-loc-trong-ngay-sinh-tho-dia-284-183720.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Phong thủy khai vận tài lộc trong ngày sinh Thổ Địa\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Phong-thuy-khai-van-tai-loc-trong-ngay-sinh-Tho-Dia.png\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/phong-thuy-khai-van-tai-loc-trong-ngay-sinh-tho-dia-284-183720.html\u0027\u003ePhong thủy khai vận tài lộc trong ngày sinh Thổ Địa\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Trong ngày sinh Thổ Địa (Thổ Công), mùng 2 tháng 2, nếu áp dụng một số tuyệt chiêu phong thủy khai vận dưới đây, tài lộc của bạn càng thêm dồi dào.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-giay-dan-tuong-hop-phong-thuy-de-tien-vao-day-hu-284-183718.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Chọn giấy dán tường hợp phong thủy để tiền vào đầy hũ\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/9/Chon-giay-dan-tuong-hop-phong-thuy-de-tien-vao-day-hu.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/chon-giay-dan-tuong-hop-phong-thuy-de-tien-vao-day-hu-284-183718.html\u0027\u003eChọn giấy dán tường hợp phong thủy để tiền vào đầy hũ\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) – Ngày nay, việc sử dụng giấy dán tường nghệ thuật để thay thế cho sơn tường trong ngôi nhà đã trở nên phổ biến. Nó không chỉ tô điểm cho không gian tươi đẹp, mà quan trọng hơn còn góp phần thúc đẩy các yếu tố phong thủy tốt, thúc đẩy tài lộc cũng như gia vận của chủ nhà.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027tin_left_1_item\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027thunal220x140\u0027\u003e\u003ca href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nhung-chu-y-khi-chuyen-nha-nhap-trach-dat-bat-huong-284-183693.html\u0027\u003e\u003cimg alt=\u0027Những chú ý khi chuyển nhà nhập trạch đặt bát hương\u0027 src=\u0027http://cms.lichngaytot.com/medias/standard/2016/3/8/Nhung-chu-y-khi-chuyen-nha-nhap-trach-dat-bat-huong.jpg\u0027\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027h3-seo\u0027\u003e\u003ca  style=\u0027font-size:14px\u0027 href=\u0027/phong-thuy/nhung-chu-y-khi-chuyen-nha-nhap-trach-dat-bat-huong-284-183693.html\u0027\u003eNhững chú ý khi chuyển nhà nhập trạch đặt bát hương\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp  style=\u0027color:#777; font-size:13px;\u0027\u003e(Lichngaytot.com) Dương trạch có ảnh hưởng rất lớn tới vận mệnh, sức khỏe, tài vận và sự nghiệp của tất cả mọi thành viên trong gia đình. Vì vậy, khi làm lễ nhập trạch cần phải chọn năm, tháng tốt. Những việc dựng cột, đổ móng thì chọn theo Nên-Kỵ của ngày. Về việc di chuyển trong nhà cũ, năm tháng thiếu thì phải chọn phương hướng tốt sau đó mới tới chọn năm tháng tốt.\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e"
```

It is not JSON DataTypes or html, so i cant parse.

Please for me suggestor, solution.

Comment: String string=  Html.fromHtml(yourhtmlstring).toString(); try this

Answer (score 0):

Use `String escaped = Html.escapeHtml(yourString);`, you will get a String with `'<'` character as `"&amp;lt;"`, instead of `'\u003c'`, and so on.
Then, use `Html.fromHtml(escaped).toString();`, you will get pure HTML that you can parse.

Also, see this question: [android html decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177889/android-html-decoding)

Answer (score 0):

You can have it in HTML this way :

```
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.SpannedString;
...

SpannedString sp = new SpannedString("your string");
String str = Html.toHtml(new SpannedString(sp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a UNICODE encoded html string.

You can first decode it to a UTF-8 string and then parse it as a normal html with something like this:

```
try {
    String string = "YOUR_DATA_FROM_API";
    byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
    string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

    //Here you can parse your string as a normal HTML
    //
    //Do stuff 

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
}
```

Comment: Have you removed the double quotes? you can check it is unicode html using this tool: http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Comment: I test on over website then success but i use code not worked. Where I was wrong? This is my code: `public void onReturnJsonObject(String jsonObject) {                              byte[] utf8 = new byte[0];                                                              try { utf8 = jsonObject.getBytes("UTF-8"); jsonObject = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");                                                                       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } Log.d(TAG, "onReturnJsonObject: "+jsonObject); }`